# Sending a message to a client and receive an answer + act on received answer

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

The Problem:
the server should send a SerialPort Command (e.g. "S") to a client and receive the port.Readline from the client AND act like send another command (e.g. "r01").

Example: Server sends "S" and receives "N" from the client so the server should send another "S". If it receives != "N" then send "r01" and so on.

I can send a message to a client but i can't receive the answer and store it/use it.

What i tried so far:

.) Save the received information into serv.connectedClients[ID].receive

Server:
The working class:

```
 public void doSomething(Service serv, string ID)
    { 
       serv.SendMessageToClient(client_name, "S");   //send first message                     
        data = serv.connectedClients[ID].receive.ToString(); //the .receive is empty but should have the clients answer stored
       if(data != ""){
          serv.SendMessageToClient(client_name, "r01");  //send second message
          serv.connectedClients[ID].Information = serv.connectedClients[ID].receive.ToString();
          }
    }
```

In the Service.cs:

```
  public void getPortMsg(string msg)
    { 
        connectedClients[OperationContext.Current.Channel.SessionId].receive = msg;
    }
```

On the Client:

```
 void callback_OnMessageReceivedEvent(string message)
    {
      string portmsg = "";
      portmsg = rfid.send(message); //portmsg gets the port.readline info
       client.getPortMsg(portmsg); //send portmsg to server

    }
```

And the rfid.send:

```
 public string send(string senden)
    {

        string data = "";
        port.WriteLine(senden);
        data = port.ReadLine();

            return data;
      }
```

The order: Server sends a message to the client. The Client receives the message and calls a service method with the answer in it. The Server should use this answer but sends the next message before he gets the answer.

Hope someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer. I don't think that this is the best way to solve the problem but it works:

Server sends the client a message + the name of the method.

The Client works with the message and writes an answer to the server + the name of the method.

The Server now knows what to do with the answer and calls the right method.

Code example:

Server:

```
public void methodA(){
   sendToClient("i want an answer",methodA);
}
```

Client:

```
 public void callback_messageFromServer(string msg,string location){
     string answer = workWithMsg(msg);
     client.sendAnswer(answer,location);
 }
```

Server:

```
public void sendAnswer(string msg, string location) {
      if(location == "methodA")
          methodB(msg);
 }
```

To call the same method i use an int count and switch(count).
Hope it helps someone ^^

Best regards